# Can torsion be negative?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, curves, tangent-line

If $B$ denotes the binormal vector, $S$ denotes the arc length, $\tau$ denotes torsion, and $N$ denotes principal normal vector, then,

$$\frac{dB}{dS} = -\Bigg|\frac{dB}{dS}\Bigg|N = -\tau N$$

So if $\tau$ is the magnitude of $\frac{dB}{dS}$, i.e. a modulus value, then how can it be negative? It is written [here](https://www.atractor.pt/mat/curvtor/notaimportante_def-_en.html) that "if torsion is positive, the curve "turns" to the side to which binormal vector points. If torsion is negative, the curve "turns" to the opposite side."

Answer (score 1):

The *definition* of the torsion of the question, i.e.
$$\frac{dB}{dS} = -\Bigg|\frac{dB}{dS}\Bigg|N = -\tau N$$ is not correct.

What is correct is that

$$\tau = -\frac{dB}{dS} \cdot N.$$ With this correct definition, the torsion can be positive as well as negative. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve?wprov=sfti1) for additional details.

Comment: But one of the Frenet–Serret formulas is $\frac{dB}{dS} = -\tau N$. And if you compare that with $\frac{dB}{dS} = -\Big|\frac{dB}{dS}\Big|N$, we get $\tau = \Big|\frac{dB}{dS}\Big|$ Why is that?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser Indeed if $\frac{dB}{dS} = -\Bigg|\frac{dB}{dS}\Bigg|N$, then $\tau = \Big|\frac{dB}{dS}\Big|$. The problem is that the equation $\frac{dB}{dS} = -\Bigg|\frac{dB}{dS}\Bigg|N$ is not correct. Where did you got that?

Comment: In my textbook (B.S. Grewal) it says "arc rate of turning of the binormal (i.e. the magnitude of $\frac{dB}{dS}$) is called torsion of the curve and is denoted by $\tau$". Also, shouldn't $\frac{dB}{dS}$ be parallel but opposite to $N$?

Comment: Then this equation was *invented* by you?

Comment: I don't understand. If torsion is the magnitude of $\frac{dB}{dS}$, shouldn't be it equal to $\Big|\frac{dB}{dS}\Big|$?

Comment: Torsion is not the magnitude.

Comment: Okay, but that's what my textbook is saying, as I already stated. I'll look more into it. On a related topic, the curvature ($\kappa$) is the magnitude of $\frac{dT}{dS}$, right?

Comment: So your book is wrong about the torsion if it says that it is a magnitude. Torsion can be negative. Curvature is indeed the magnitude of $\frac{dT}{dS}$.

Comment: Can I say torsion is equal to $\pm\Big|\frac{dB}{dS}\Big|$?